# Error vs residual in simple linear regression

Tags: least-squares, linear-regression

In my textbook the following definition were presented

[image: LS method]

However, it was presented previously that [image: regression definition]

Thus if we were to minimise the sum of squared **residuals**, shouldn't we be minimising $Q=\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i-\hat{y})^2=\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i-\hat{\beta_0}-\hat{\beta_1}x_i)^2$?

Comment: Here, $\hat \beta_0$ denotes the value that minimizes $Q$, which you are trying to **find**, whereas $\beta_0$ is the **current** value in your model.

Comment: @hff1 does that mean the $\beta_0$ in the first definition is different from the $\beta_0$ in the regression model definition? Where $\beta_0$ is the true parameter in $y_i=\beta_0+\beta_1x_i+\epsilon_i$ and $\beta_0$ in equation $Q$ is simply a variable that represents some arbitrary value we started with?

Comment: They are the same and can be arbitrary.

Answer (score 1):

You may understand in this way that $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$, they denote a solution of $Q$, while $\hat{\beta}_0$ and $\hat{\beta}_1$, they are an optimal solution for the minimization problem $Q$.